# PHP get MySQL database as associative array by row

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a simple mySQL database table that I am loading into a PHP array. I would like the `id` column of the mySQL table (which is auto incremented, but I don't think that's relevant) to be the array key for each element of the PHP array, instead of the array being numeric.

Instead of this:

```
Array(
  Array(id=>'1', field1=>someval, field2=>val),
  Array(id=>'2', field1=>val, field2=>otherval),
  Array(id=>'4', field1=>val, field2=>otherval)
)
```

I want this:

```
Array(
  1=>Array(field1=>someval, field2=>val),
  2=>Array(field1=>val, field2=>otherval),
  4=>Array(field1=>val, field2=>otherval)
)
```

I don't care if `id` is left in the associative array for each row.

Is there a way to do this without looping through the original mySQL array and using up lots of processing time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is there a way to do this without looping through the original mySQL array and using up lots of processing time?"

I believe the answer to this is **no**. The best you can do is to try to be as efficient as possible when looping through the array.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it at the fetch time like this:

```
$query_ret = mysql_query(...);
$result = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_ret)) {
    $result[array_shift($row)] = $row;
}
```

Comment: @Hammerite Didn't read the question? I think the original mySQL array which OP means is the $result array after fetch loop, you can make it at the fetch loop time, not another loop to change it after the fetch loop, the fetch loop is a must, isn't it?

Comment: When the OP says "original MySQL array", he means the MySQL result object contained in your `$result`. He asks for a way to achieve the end-result of your code, but without using the `while` loop in your code. But since your interpretation is a result of (what I see as being) misunderstanding rather than failing to read the question, I remove my downvote.

Comment: It turns out I cannot remove my downvote because it was too long ago that I placed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have PDO, you should definitely see Example #3 from the PDO documentation for fetchall: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php#example-1022

Not only is this way more efficient use of your server's memory and processing power... it would also enable you to take advantage of several of PDO's other powerful APIs.